# Making floating images to have the same margin

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any simple solution to make floating images to all have the same margin with the images on top of them?

I have a container with 40+ images. All images are of the same width but different height. They look fine when the page loads, but resizing the browser makes the images to stick to the ones with bigger height and so one row might end up having only one image and lot's of empty . What I want is the images to have the same space between them vertically.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yuwrp/

The only way I can think of is to have the container positioned relative and the images positioned absolute and use Javascript to calculate  how many columns of images will be there based on container's width, store sum of heights in an array and use it to place the next images.
I probably can achieve that, but looking for a simpler solution.

Thanks.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container{overflow: hidden;}
    #container > img{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        /* height varies for images */
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <img src="" />
    <!-- more images -->
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Use classes. They allow you to apply styles to multiple elements with the same class.

Comment: Each image has a different height, I'm gonna need to give each one of them a different margin-top in that case and still it leaves me with lower number of images in some rows. Or you mean I should do something else with the classes?

Comment: If you give each of your images a class of `foo`, then you can apply a style to all of them with the CSS, `.foo { property: value }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `float: left`, you can use:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yuwrp/1/

Or change the `vertical-align` to `middle` or `bottom` depending on how you want them aligned.